# Authorization Using Olingo and JPA

Tags: java, jpa, odata, olingo

I'm using JPA and Olingo for some REST services. I was able to get the basic implementation working with my entities similar to the example here: [JPA Olingo Web App](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/CreateWebApp.html).

However Now I'm trying to add authorization where I join to access tables and then filter the results accordingly. I'm just wondering if there is a good way of doing this without having to override default behavior. I have seen the annotation processor here [Annotation Processor](https://wiki.apache.org/Olingo/Documentation/AnnotationProcessor) for EDM but it doesn't seem to fit our model very well.

My question is this: Is there an easy way to change the Olingo JPA Processor to join tables and filter entities by default in order to implement authorization? This will require me to be able to pass in accounts to filter and also limit all results.

I have also tried pre-processing and post-processing as described here.  [Custom JPA Processor](http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/CustomODataJPAProcessor.html) However, the filtering needs to be done in the query not after returning the results because the JPA query will return too many results and is long and costly to convert thousands of objects.

So far I've implemented a CustomODataJPAProcessor. However, it will require me to now rewrite and override the org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.core.access.data.JPAProcessorImpl#processmethod and modify the JPA Query with my desired functionality. You'll see that I implemented a new JPAProcessor where I call process and send in my accounts. Here's what my code looks like in the readEntitySet method of my CustomODataJPAProcessor:

```
    /* Pre Process Step */
    preprocess( );
    List<String> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    //This is what the original readEntitySet does
    //ODataJPAFactory.createFactory().getODataJPAAccessFactory().getODataJPAResponseBuilder(oDataJPAContext);

    //Using custom JPA Processor that I added
    jpaProcessor = new CustomJPAProcessor(this.oDataJPAContext);
    CustomJPAProcessor customJPAProcessor = (CustomJPAProcessor)jpaProcessor;
    List<Object> jpaEntities = customJPAProcessor.process(uriParserResultView, accounts);

    //What the docs want you to do http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/CustomODataJPAProcessor.html
    //java.util.List<Object> jpaEntities = jpaProcessor.process(uriParserResultView);

   /* Post Process Step */
    postProcess( );
```

Comment: I am working on similar problem too but I am going to use JDBC wrapper to parse and transform SQL so that I can secure  DML and native queries too. Native row level security is a better option if you do not need cross db support and your DB supports query transformation (Oracel, MS SQL,PostgreSQL,DB2 support Rls out of the box)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555979/authorization-using-apache-olingo-v2-jpa

Comment: I used the following tutorial for making JWT auth in olingo with spring boot: https://medium.com/swlh/spring-boot-security-jwt-hello-world-example-b479e457664c

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you are stil working on it.
I am working on this problem right now.
Olingo provide the ODataJPAQueryExtensionEntityListener this listener is execute by JPAQueryBuilder one step before the execution of the buildQuery.

With this stateless listener you can replace the buildQuery methods so you can access and change the string jpqlStatement.toString() that contain the JPQL query.

I think is better then the native SQL

bye
Domenico

Comment: Could you please add some sample code or share it via GitHub?

Comment: I will ...if I have time but check this howto for me very useful https://www.baeldung.com/olingo (git:https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/apache-olingo)

In the EntityManagerWrapper in the createQuery method you have the actual query string.

Unfortunately I am still not able to access the uri information but I think it is possible to store the object with a class that wrap the ODataJPAProcessorDefault method: readEntity and readEntitySet (I am interested only in read operation).

Comment: You can access to uri information like this: `URI uri = oDataContext.getPathInfo().getRequestUri(); List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(uri, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 0):

[Source of this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/spring-boot-security-jwt-hello-world-example-b479e457664c)

**I have used this tutorial for making JWT auth in this [olingo JPA app](https://github.com/jpenninkhof/odata-boilerplate). I have just copied the whole content for future that if the source link is not anymore valid, people could have this chance to access it!**

*You need to adapt the sample for your usecase, i.e. the packages must change and the libraries must added to pom.xml file. Of course you don't need to add `HelloWorldController` but add the rest files to the similar folders in your application and it will request for jwt token before serving `odata.csv/$metadata` or the rest of the requests!*

## Spring Boot Security + JWT Hello World Example - The Startup

In this tutorial, we will be developing a Spring Boot application that makes use of JWT authentication for securing an exposed REST API. In this example, we will be making use of hard-coded user values for user authentication. In the next section, we will be implementing Spring Boot + JWT + MYSQL JPA for storing and fetching user credentials. Any user will be able to consume this API only if it has a valid JSON Web Token (JWT).

For better understanding, we will be developing the project in stages:

Develop a Spring Boot application that exposes a simple REST GET API with mapping /hello.

Configure Spring Security for JWT. Expose REST POST API with mapping/authenticate using which User will get a valid JSON Web Token. And then, allow the user access to the API /hello only if it has a valid token

[image]

### Develop a Spring Boot Application That Exposes a GET REST API

The Maven project will look as follows:

[image]

The pom.xml is as follows:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

#### Create a Controller class for exposing a GET REST API-

```java
package com.javainuse.controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping({ "/hello" })
    public String firstPage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

#### Create the bootstrap class with Spring Boot Annotation

```java
package com.javainuse;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootHelloWorldApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### Compile and the run the SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java as a Java application.

Go to **localhost:8080/hello**

[image]

### Spring Security and JWT Configuration

We will be configuring Spring Security and JWT for performing 2 operations-

- **Generating JWT** — Expose a POST API with mapping **/authenticate**. On passing correct username and password it will generate a JSON Web Token(JWT)
- **Validating JWT** — If user tries to access GET API with mapping **/hello**. It will allow access only if request has a valid JSON Web Token(JWT)

Maven Project will be as follows-

[image]

The sequence flow for these operations will be as follows-

### Generating JWT

[image]

[image]

### Validating JWT

[image]

Add the Spring Security and JWT dependencies

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Define the application.properties. We specify the secret key using which we will be using for hashing algorithm. The secret key is combined with the header and the payload to create a unique hash. We are only able to verify this hash if you have the secret key.

```
jwt.secret=javainuse
```

### JwtTokenUtil

The JwtTokenUtil is responsible for performing JWT operations like creation and validation.It makes use of the io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts for achieving this.

```java
package com.javainuse.config;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2550185165626007488L;
    public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 5 * 60 * 60;
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;
    //retrieve username from jwt token
    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }
    //retrieve expiration date from jwt token
    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }
    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    //for retrieveing any information from token we will need the secret key
    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }
    //check if the token has expired
    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }
    //generate token for user
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }
    //while creating the token -
    //1. Define  claims of the token, like Issuer, Expiration, Subject, and the ID
    //2. Sign the JWT using the HS512 algorithm and secret key.
    //3. According to JWS Compact Serialization(https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-41#section-3.1)
    //   compaction of the JWT to a URL-safe string 
    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
    }
    //validate token
    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

### JWTUserDetailsService

JWTUserDetailsService implements the Spring Security UserDetailsService interface. It overrides the loadUserByUsername for fetching user details from the database using the username. The Spring Security Authentication Manager calls this method for getting the user details from the database when authenticating the user details provided by the user. Here we are getting the **user details from a hardcoded User List**. Also the password for a user is stored in encrypted format using BCrypt.

```java
package com.javainuse.service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if ("javainuse".equals(username)) {
            return new User("javainuse", "$2a$10$slYQmyNdGzTn7ZLBXBChFOC9f6kFjAqPhccnP6DxlWXx2lPk1C3G6",
                    new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
    }
}
```

### JwtAuthenticationController

Expose a POST API /authenticate using the JwtAuthenticationController. The POST API gets username and password in the body- Using Spring Authentication Manager we authenticate the username and password.If the credentials are valid, a JWT token is created using the JWTTokenUtil and provided to the client.

```java
package com.javainuse.controller;
import java.util.Objects;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.javainuse.service.JwtUserDetailsService;
import com.javainuse.config.JwtTokenUtil;
import com.javainuse.model.JwtRequest;
import com.javainuse.model.JwtResponse;
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtAuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }
    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
    }
}
```

### JwtRequest

This class is required for storing the username and password we recieve from the client.

```java
package com.javainuse.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class JwtRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5926468583005150707L;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    //need default constructor for JSON Parsing
    public JwtRequest()
    {

    }
    public JwtRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.setUsername(username);
        this.setPassword(password);
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

### JwtResponse

This is class is required for creating a response containing the JWT to be returned to the user.

```java
package com.javainuse.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class JwtResponse implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8091879091924046844L;
    private final String jwttoken;
    public JwtResponse(String jwttoken) {
        this.jwttoken = jwttoken;
    }
    public String getToken() {
        return this.jwttoken;
    }
}
```

### JwtRequestFilter

The JwtRequestFilter extends the Spring Web Filter OncePerRequestFilter class. For any incoming request this Filter class gets executed. It checks if the request has a valid JWT token. If it has a valid JWT Token then it sets the Authentication in the context, to specify that the current user is authenticated.

```java
package com.javainuse.config;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import com.javainuse.service.JwtUserDetailsService;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }
        // Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
            // authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

### JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint

This class will extend Spring's AuthenticationEntryPoint class and override its method commence. It rejects every unauthenticated request and send error code 401

```java
package com.javainuse.config;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7858869558953243875L;
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

### WebSecurityConfig

This class extends the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is a convenience class that allows customization to both WebSecurity and HttpSecurity.

```java
package com.javainuse.config;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

### Start the Spring Boot Application

- Generate a JSON Web Token -
- Create a POST request with url `localhost:8080/authenticate`. Body should have valid username and password. In our case username is `javainuse` and password is `password`.

[image]

- Validate the JSON Web Token
- Try accessing the url `localhost:8080/hello` using the above generated token in the header as follows

[image]