# Authorization using Apache Olingo V2 / JPA

Tags: jpa, odata, olingo

I am trying to implement a custom authorization scheme for an OData2 server which is exposed using the Apache Olingo JPA annotation processor; the authorization involves a basic user:operation pair to restrict query/update/insert/delete operations on the database; the idea is to secure the server layer (Tomcat) via username/password, and then propagating the user id to the OData layer to perform the permission check.

Has anyone implemented something similar? My current approach involves extending the ODataJPAProcessor and making the checks in the relevant methods (readEntity, updateEntity, etc.); however I am not sure if this would be the best way forward.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
-Eduardo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorization Using Olingo and JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198106/authorization-using-olingo-and-jpa)

Comment: I used the following tutorial for making JWT auth in olingo: https://medium.com/swlh/spring-boot-security-jwt-hello-world-example-b479e457664c

Answer (score 1):

On my project we used identity provider and JWT token. Token was validated and used in the exposed OData servlet and all the permission checks were inside the processors.  We used a Decorator design pattern to wrap standard processors with the `Secured` ones and only the `Secured` ones were allowed inside OData handler.

I cannot guarantee that it is the best approach, but it sounds reasonable.

Comment: Could you please add some sample code or share it via Github?